# Error a la hora de ejecutar .jar NOTE: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details. adjunto proyecto

Tags: java, api

Adjunto el link del proyecto por si sirve de algo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]www.mediafire.com/file/08n1ss6c9b9brh6/Mam%E1API.rar/file

Comment: Hola @David, bienvenido! Cuando hagas una pregunta asegúrate de agregar el código, o la parte de este, que puede ser relevante para la comprensión de tu problema. Así como todos aquellos detalles que nos pongan en contexto. Por ejemplo, en tu caso, estás teniendo un problema con el uso de un API marcada como deprecated en el archivo Frame.java. Agrega el código de esta clase y dinos con que versión del JDK estás trabajando.

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si compilas el proyecto con la opción `-Xlint:deprecation`, como te dice el mensaje de la consola, puedes tener los detalles del API que estás usando y que está marcado como `deprecated`.

En tu caso lo que ocurre es que estás usando el método [JPasswordField#getText()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JPasswordField.html#getText()), en las líneas 166 y 169, el cual está marcado como `deprecated` desde al parecer la versión 1.2 de Java según se lee en el javadoc.

> **Deprecated.** *As of Java 2 platform v1.2, replaced by getPassword.*

Según la propia documentación la recomendación es usar [JPasswordField#getPassword()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JPasswordField.html#getPassword()).

***Es importante aclarar que esto es un `warning` por lo que no es impedimento para que tu código se compile y ejecute sin problemas.***

De todos modos, si quieres corregir esto aquí va la solución. Nota como he modificado parte del método `setButtonsIngreso()` que es donde está el código problemático. Exactamente dentro de la definición de la acción del botón `Ingresar`.

```
    ingreso.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
            if (!ingUsuario.getText().equals(usser)) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "El usuario ingresado es incorrecto", "Error al ingresar usuario", 0);
            } else if (!Arrays.equals(ingClave.getPassword(), clave.toCharArray())) {// Como getPassword devuelve un char[] tengo que comparar de este modo
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "La clave que ingreso es incorrecta", "Error al ingresar Clave", 0);
            }

            // Como getPassword devuelve un char[] tengo que comparar de este modo
            if (ingUsuario.getText().equals(usser) && Arrays.equals(ingClave.getPassword(), clave.toCharArray())) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Bienvenida mamita", "Acceso autorizado", 3);
                frameInicio.dispose();
                makeAplicacion();
            }
        }
    });
```

Fuera de el problema que planteas, te propongo una mejora para que evites repetir la comprobación de usuario y contraseña. Una vez que haces las primeras comprobaciones, si estas fallan puedes agregar un `return` dentro del bloque del `if` y así sabes que si llega la ajecución abajo de estas comprobaciones es porque fueron satisfactorias.

```
    ingreso.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
            if (!ingUsuario.getText().equals(usser)) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "El usuario ingresado es incorrecto", "Error al ingresar usuario", 0);
                return;// Como falla la comprobación termino la ejecución del método
            } else if (!Arrays.equals(ingClave.getPassword(), clave.toCharArray())) {// Como getPassword devuelve un char[] tengo que comparar de este modo
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "La clave que ingreso es incorrecta", "Error al ingresar Clave", 0);
                return;// Como falla la comprobación termino la ejecución del método
            }

            // Si llega aquí es porque las comprobaciones fueron satisfactorias por lo tanta el acceso se otorga
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Bienvenida mamita", "Acceso autorizado", 3);
            frameInicio.dispose();
            makeAplicacion();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Mil gracias, lo tendré en cuenta y solucionare. Posiblemente tenga muchos fallos hasta apenas estoy aprendiendo pero muchas gracias :D

Comment: @DavidNuñez los fallos y trpiezos son parte de todo proceso de aprendizaje, lo importante es no desistir. Saludos.